In .NET core WinForms controls text size changes in response to Windows Scale Text Size
In my .NET 8 C# WinForms applications, when the system text size is changed (via System->Display->Scale->Text size), most of my controls runtime font sizes change (except for textbox for some reason). None of my control font sizes are set explicitly in code. I noticed the same behavior in .NET 7.
When my applications were .NET framework 4.8, this behavior did not occur (font sizes for all controls was unaffected by Scale->Text size changes and the designer code was identical to the .NET 8 version).
My forms are all set to AutoScaleMode=Dpi in .NET 8 (same as under framework 4.8).
For .NET 8, I use:
Application.SetHighDpiMode(HighDpiMode.PerMonitorV2);

It there a setting I can make to cause changes in Windows Scale Text size to be ignored, as they were in .NET Framework?

Honestly: the old behavior was bad. If the user wants to scale the text, you should do the work to make the form respond well, rather than have your app look different and wrong compared to the rest of the system.

@JoelCoehoorn - Point taken - I'm just trying to keep the WinForms apps up to date until Microsoft actually finishes WinUI3, so for now I have to rely on the default AutoScaleMode behavior (even though after all these years it still isn't quite right).
